# Simple javascript onclick not working

Tags: javascript

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5UXkA/

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="test()" />
</body>
</html>​
```

JavaScript:

```
function test() {
    alert('hi');
}​
```

As expected, it is not alerting the data!

Comment: why the downvote?? seems a perfectly valid question

Comment: You might want to put a little more effort into the question.  You know, *any* effort.  How is it not working?  What errors are you getting?  Post the code here.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but: Fiddles are a nice bonus, but you should *always* post relevant code in the question itself.  Also, you'll usually need to clarify "not working": at the very least, do you see any errors? (Seeing no errors at all is also worth reporting.)

Comment: ohk. so any answers now?

Comment: You didn't ask a question or provide any relevant details, such as what its supposed to do.

Comment: On the left look at the first dropdown list: "OnLoad". Change it to No Wrap Head or No Wrap body.

Comment: Also look at your JS console when you're testing something. You would have seen the error "test is not defined" which would have maybe led you somewhere, or which you could have included here to help us.

Answer (score 7):

ditch the html and body tags, change from onload to nowrap. See http://jsfiddle.net/5UXkA/5/

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I found was in the fiddle.  Your function `test()` was not defined when your the fiddle called it.

I put your javascript in new head tags in the html and it worked.  For the purposes of using a fiddle, just use '`onDomReady`' instead of `onLoad`.
http://jsfiddle.net/5UXkA/10/

Comment: has nothing to do with his button.. not your fault, question was unclear 2 minutes ago..

Comment: Where do I indicate that my solution involves the button?  I see my language is vague though

Comment: You said: 'I put your javascript in new head tags in the html and it worked.'    Looking at your [jsfiddle.net/5UXkA/10](http://jsfiddle.net/5UXkA/10/), you weren't even kidding: you actually entered a full html (ex mandatory title-tag) into the html-body-area of jsfiddle. This is not how jsfiddle works!    Further-more, the topic-title clearly says: 'onclick not working'.    Logically this did not work, since in the background of jsfiddle this function was wrapped in a onload function... closures/scope anyone?    Just want to clear this up for future readers!