# Can't execute simple JS by onclick from a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is almost embarassingly simple. I haven't touch JS for a while and now I can't do anything while clicking on a button...

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/e1qnsxkb/2/) shows what I mean.

```
Click below
<div id='holder'></div>
<input type='button' value='below' onclick='onClick()'>

function onClick() {
  alert('beep');
}
```

Smack me if it's something obvious. Which it most likely is...

Comment: Try placing the script `before` the input.

Comment: @Eric How do I do that on jsFiddle page? There are three different text areas for the that...

Comment: Top-left i for HTML, top-right is for CSS, bottom-left is JS and the last one is the outcome

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct fiddle? It has nothing to do with the script you actually have posted above.

Comment: The fiddle you linked here is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @briosheje Forgot to save...

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense :P

Comment: @aSharma Now it is. Saving **before** sharing the link, you know. Complicated stuff if you're dumb...   :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e1qnsxkb/3/ You forgot to add jQuery to your fiddle. Besides, you can just use the comfortable jQuery .on

Comment: @briosheje Why include jQuery when it's pure JS?

Comment: @Justinas, "$('holder').html("hjkl");" isn't pure JS

Comment: The Frameworks and Extensions section in the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1qnsxkb/10/)** change *Onload* to  *No Wrap - in <body>*

Comment: You need to define the function before you assign it to onClick. See here, I have updated your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/e1qnsxkb/11/

Comment: @Justinas: Did you FIRST read the question and the fiddle before posting? There is the jQuery tag in the OP's question and, in the fiddle, he is using jQuery WITHOUT including it. Why on Earth would you add a pure javascript event listener when you can do that using jQuery? Also, using "inline" javascript event listeners on HTML seems to be considered bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice . And this is the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e1qnsxkb/13/

Comment: @aSharma You need to post that as a reply. That **was** the problem. Has it been changed on the site? I don't recall ever needing to set the combo box...

Comment: No, it is not changed on the site, it is merely an updated version of your fiddle. You can see the difference in the url. If you don't recall the settings on Fiddle, may be you need this http://doc.jsfiddle.net/ Happy javascripting.

Comment: Similar Questions can be found [here][1] and [here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657186/simple-javascript-onclick-not-working
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114747/onclick-event-not-firing-on-jsfiddle-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171008/onclick-not-working-with-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the function before you assign it to `onClick`. See here, I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1qnsxkb/11).

Additionally I have commented you Jquery code, didn't think it was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>

<script>
function onClick() {
  alert('beep');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='below' onclick='onClick()'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you changed and why it fixes problem?

Comment: He defined onClick function before DOM was created.

Comment: @Jeremen Don't spoil. Let him figure it out himself!

Comment: @Jeremen In jsFiddle, I have different frames for that. How do I do that **there**?!

Comment: @Konrad Your code is fine, but in your fiddle you are linking the js "on load", meaning your function is defined after the DOM creation. There is an option in that dropdown to place the js in the head section (which is what Ramkumar has done).

Comment: @KonradViltersten, in Frameworks & Extensions section in second select choose a "**No wrap - in <head>**" option.